# How to expose a website on the new VMs in Azure?

Tags: azure, iis

I used to use the "classic" VMs to host test web sites on Azure, but now when I create a VM using the new Azure portal I don't get the option to create a cloud service when I create the VM and can't seem to figure out how to hook up the VM to a cloud service.
My requirement is simple, I have a third party BA web site that I need to install and test.  The site gets installed and runs fine locally in IIS but I can't seem to expose it as a ".cloudapp.net" site.
Thanks in advance,
Vince

Answer (score 0):

Cloud services do not exist in the new portal (known as ARM). Instead you should be creating a load balancer or traffic manager resource in front of the VM and then configuring access that way.

A number of considerations will be needed before picking which method to go with, for example [traffic manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/traffic-manager/) profiles can only be pointed at Web Apps, classic cloud services or ARM based network adapters on VMs with public IP addresses. Your public IP address must have a DNS name associated with it as well.

For [load balancers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-load-balance/), you have more options in some areas over traffic manager profiles but it really does depend on your requirements.

Personally I use traffic manager profiles for providing access to IaaS VMs.